# How to Re-publish Web App without changing URL

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, publish

We've published a Google Script as a Web App and thus the resulting URLfor that web app.  Works great. Of course, after publishing, there were some changes made to the script.  The question is, we're not sure how to "re-publish" (update, if you will) the web app WITHOUT changing its URL, which users now have and have probably bookmarked, etc.  I'd hate to "Publish" or "re-publish"  wrong and render the old URL as unavailable or dated (i.e. only reflecting the prior version of the script). We want the updated web app to result in an unchanged URL.

Comment: Just publish  and deploy it will  keep the same url  unless  you disabled it and even then I not sure if it changes or not.  You can answer this question yourself by just writing another simple webapp and testing it yourself.

Comment: Thanks.  Just didn't see a "Re-Publish" option per se and got concerned.   Brilliant suggestion (create a test web app),  Thanks.  Did just that, made a copy with a new name and published it. Then,  made some edits, saved as a new version, then published the new version  and BINGO.  The URL was unchanged and the web app rflected the change with with the same URL. Thanks for helping this total rookie.

Answer (score 2):

Quick steps for googlers like me

1. Save code edits.
2. At the top, click Deploy > Manage deployments.
3. Select the deployment and click Edit.
4. Select new version of the code (that was the main trick).
5. Click deploy. Changes now took effect for the same url.

There're [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#edit_a_versioned_deployment) but it takes effort to read and do not exactly answer the question